# Access 'DONE' button on 'create new contact' form in android

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android and have a following problem.

I had created OCR app in android. After OCR'ing the text, details are fetched and prefilled in add new contact form of android. When we click 'Done' button, the details are saved in phonebook and page is navigated to phonebook.

I want to navigate the page to my app. when user clicks 'Done' button.
I don't know how to change click event of the button, as it is predefined by the android OS.

Sample code for 'add new contact'

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
 intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
 intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, fName);
 intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,phno.toString());
 intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL,email);
 startActivity(intent);
```

I am using 
eclipse adt bundle for android development
Ubuntu 12.04

Any Help will be appreciated...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well first thing you cannot change the behavior of Done button and let that application run on device.

I am not sure but the hint I can give you is in such case you may try `android.database.ContentObserver` to listen for the changes.and you can take appropriate action when change occurs.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, new MyObserver());
}

class MyObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public MyObserver() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something Changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode) to wait for the result from the new contact screen. Just override the onActivityResult method in your activity like so:

```
private static final int NEW_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE = 0;    

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == NEW_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Check if the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Contact added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and modify your 'add new contact' code to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, fName);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,phno.toString());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL,email);
if (Integer.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK) > 14) {
    intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
}
startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE);
```